# +resolveClassMethod are invoked when I'm trying to get bundle for this class

Tags: ios

I want to reload `+ (BOOL)resolveClassMethod:(SEL)sel` method to add my custom implementation of unresolved methods in super class, like this:

```
+ (BOOL)resolveClassMethod:(SEL)sel {
    BOOL result = [super resolveClassMethod:sel];
    if (result) {
        return result;
    }

    /*my logic here*/

}
```

But I notice that, when I call `+bundleForClass:` method with this class it actually invokes `resolveClassMethod:` with `bundleForClass:` selector as parameter. And, of course, `[super resolveClassMethod:sel];` return NO and it move to my logic. Code:

```
NSBundle *classBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:NSClassFromString(@"MyClass")];
```

Why code above invoke `+resolveClassMethod:` on MyClass? I aim to add implementation for my custom class methods to class, but not implementation of standard method like `bundleForClass:`, so how can I check methods like that to skip it.